# Backup remote Oracle Database with C#

Tags: c#, sql, .net, database, oracle

I need to backup an Oracle 19c database remotely without any third party tools, so no RMAN or EXP/IMP.

I was wondering if there is something comparable to the "BACKUP"  SQL command from MSSQL, or Microsofts SQL Server Management Objects or even MySqlBackup.Net.

Any help would be appreciated!

**Edit:**

I am sorry for the confusion caused by this question, still new to the platform.
I forgot to mention, that I am currently working on a C# project, which should allow users to backup an Oracle database or a SQL Server database remotely. It is a part of a bigger project and should be incorporated later on. The user would have to enter a connection string and some other parameters and my library would then create the backups of the specified databases.

SQL Server backups were pretty easy to implement thanks to SQL Server Management Objects, but as far as I know Oracle does not have an C# library like that.

To reiterate, I need to write a C# tool, which can connect to the Oracle database via a connection string and then backup the database to a specified folder.
This folder will most likely be a shared folder, to allow the user access to the created backup.
Are there any tools, that would allow this? Maybe something similar to SMO or to MySqlBackup.NET? If there aren't any, I would most likely use PL/SQL and either use `DBMS_SCHEDULER` to create and run a `BACKUP-SCRIPT` type job or use `DBMS_DATAPUMP`. I think those would be possible solutions, but I am not familiar with them, so I am still unsure.

Again, I am sorry if I caused any confusion with my initial question and thank you for every answer!

Comment: Why do you consider rman to be a third party tool?  And why would you not want to use the very tool that was designed for backing up oracle databases?

Comment: Your question says 'no third party tool', so what does this has to do with C#? Aside from that, why have such constraints? This seems like an XY-Problem to me: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XY_problem

Comment: The only supported onilne backup of an Oracle database for physical recovery is using rman. If you're looking for _logical_ backups (just data and object defs), then use expdp to ensure full object compatibility. These are Oracle tools included in the database install, not "3rd party" tools. Anything else that you build yourself will not be supported and will most likely not work. The old "exp" command works remotely to do a data dump, but it might not catch all database object types. Oracle has mostly engineered true backup commands NOT to go to remote locations for security purposes.